# Retrieve gmails which contain "match" in the subject line

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I would like to write some javascript which will log in to my gmail, and print the last ten emails which contain the word "match".

I have attempted, and so far I've gotten the below. Note that the line

```
if ( messages[i].title.indexOf("match") !== -1; ) {
```

doesn't work, but I am not sure how to access the title of each message (and I'm unsure is this the best way to search for a sub-string?).

Also, how do I access the actual email content and print that rather than the ID, like I am doing here :

```
output += messages[i].id + "<br>";
```

Here is the code extract -

```
   function listMessages() {
    var userId = "me";
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': userId
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var messages = resp.messages;
      var output = "<br>Query returned " + messages.length + " messages:<br>";
      for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        if ( messages[i].title.indexOf(substring) !== -1; ) {
            output += messages[i].id + "<br>";
        }
    }
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += output;
    });
  }
```

But this just allows me to print the ID of the message, not the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

The gmail API has the ability to add a q parameter to the list method [Gmail Filter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

The raw call would look like this

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="subject:match"

Doing it this way you are only returning the messages that contain match in the subject

A wild guess would be trying to do something like `request.q = "subject:match"` but i have limited knowledge of the js client library.  `document.getElementById("content")` should be the message content